# Plot data from pandas DataFrame, colour of points dependant on a column

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization

I have a pandas DataFrame with 3 columns, shown below.

`col1   value           flag
 1       0              0
 2       0.03915        0
 3       0.13           1`

I want to create a scatterplot from this dataframe where `col1` is the x axis and `value` is the y axis, and the part I'm struggling to do is, for the rows that have `flag=0` I want the color of this point to be blue and similarly if `flag=1` I want to color the point red.

Is there a simple to to check the flag column per row and color the point accordingly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the built-in `df.plot.scatter()` function and pass the `flag` column to the `color` argument:

```
import pandas as pd

idx = [1,2,3]
value = [0., 0.03, 0.13]
flag = [0, 0, 1]

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(idx=idx, value=value, flag=flag))

df.plot.scatter('idx', 'value', c='flag', cmap='RdBu_r')
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the dataframe containing the given data is `df`, this is what you want.
You can create a list of colors according to your condition `flag` column and its values. Feed that colors list to `color` argument in the built-in `DataFrame.plot.scatter` function. (You can find the docs [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.scatter.html).)

```
colors = ['r' if flag==1 else 'b' for flag in df.flag]
df.plot.scatter('col1', 'value', color=colors)
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a vector to the scatter plot as follows

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'value':[0, 0.4, 0.13], 'flag':[0,0,1]})
plt.scatter(df['value'], df.index, c=df['flag'])
```

[image]